# Why `lower, upper = 0, N;` will make lower = 1 and upper = 0?

Tags: c

Today I'm reading 《C-Programming》, when I'm copying the code from the book of a fahr-celsius converting function.

I saw codes like

```
int lower, upper;
lower = 0;
upper = 300;
```

And I'm wondering If I can do

```
int lower, upper;
lower, upper = 0, 300
```

in C, just like in python and golang.

So I did some experiment, I find if I did it, the file is compilable, but the result will be out of my expectation.

Here is my code and output:

```
# code

#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int lower, upper;
    lower, upper = 0, 300;

    printf("lower:%d\n", lower);
    printf("upper:%d\n", upper);
}


# output
lower:1
upper:0
```

I found no matter what number I tried assign to upper(like 1, -5, 20), the output will be the same.

What happened here?

Comment: `0, 300` is an expression that evaluates to `300`. There are no lists or tuples or whatever in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C doesn't support assigning tuples like Python does.

What this code does:

```
lower, upper = 0, 300
```

Is as follows:

- Evaluate `lower` which is uninitialized, discard the resulting value
- Assign 0 to `upper`
- Evaluate the value 300

If you want to assign to two variables you need to do them separately, i.e.

```
lower = 0;  upper = 300;
```

Comment: Or `int lower = 0, upper = 300;`

Comment: Technically, evaluating `lower` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Why discard the resulting value will leads to lower = 1(the print result)

Comment: @Zen It doesn't.  `lower` is uninitialized, so it's value is *indeterminate*.  Attempting to read it causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so *any* value could be printed.